# How to implement the pagination in blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination, blazor

I have an API which takes skip and top parameters and returning the list of data. I am integrating that API in blazor client. Here how can I implement the pagination by passing skip and top values from client
Below are my code sample
index.razor

```
 @page "/";
    @inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
    @uisng App.services
    @inject HttpClient _httpClient
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, " Pending Data")" 
   id="defaultOpen">Pending Data</button> </div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Appointment</th>
            <th>Created Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @if (pamilist != null)
        {
            @foreach (var p in pamilist)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@p.id</td>
                    <td>@p.appointmentXid</td>
                    <td>@p.created</td>

                </tr>

            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code
{
    private Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> jsModuleTask;
    private string patientInfo;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        jsModuleTask = new(() => jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/component.js").AsTask());
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var jsModule = await jsModuleTask.Value;
            patientInfo = await jsModule.InvokeAsync<string>("getPatientInfo"); await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        }
    }

    public List<Pami> pamilist { get; set; } = new List<Pami>();

    [Inject]
    public IPamiHttpRepository ProductRepo { get; set; }
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        pamilist = await ProductRepo.PatientsWithPagination(int skip, int top)();
    }
}
```

How can I pass skip and top values to PatientsWithPagination(int skip, int top) method in OnInitializedAsync()?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBGiV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obUjo.png)

Httprepository.cs

```
public async Task<List<Pami>> PatientsWithPagination(int skip, int top)
{
  var url = Path.Combine("patientinfo", skip.ToString(), top.ToString()); 
  var response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
  var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
 throw new ApplicationException(content)
}
var patients = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Pami>>(content, _options); 
return patients;
}
```

Program.cs

```
using BlazorApp1;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:7823/api/") });

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

In program.cs file I added the third party endpoint url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5j6e.png)

Can any one please help me on how to implement the pagination

Comment: Please use `code sections` instead of images.

Comment: Thanks @T.Trassoudaine Please look now I added code snippets